# React Native and Refs - Why does this function not return my content?

Tags: javascript, react-native, reactjs

I have the following code in react native:

```
'use strict'

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Animated, Dimensions, Easing, Image, Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

const categoryTwoLinks = [
  { label: 'Subcategory1' },
  { label: 'Subcategory2' },
  { label: 'Subcategory3' },
  { label: 'Subcategory4' },
  { label: 'Subcategory5' },
  { label: 'Subcategory6' },
]

const categoryTouts = [
  { image: require('./assets/images/image01.jpg'), title: 'Category1' },
  { image: require('./assets/images/image02.jpg'), title: 'Category2', links: categoryTwoLinks },
  { image: require('./assets/images/image03.jpg'), title: 'Category3' },
]

class Tout extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('tout')
    return (
      <Image
        source={this.props.image}
        ratioGrow
        alignItems='center'
        style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}
      >
        <Text
          style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 24, backgroundColor: 'transparent', fontWeight: 'bold' }}
        >
          {this.props.title}
        </Text>
      </Image>
    )
  }
}

export default class scrollAccordion extends Component {

  handleScroll = ({ nativeEvent: { contentOffset } }: Object) => {
    const scrollY = contentOffset.y
    this.scrollOffsetValue.setValue(scrollY)
  }

  setScrollRef = node => {
    console.log('set scroll ref')
    if (node) {
      this.scrollRef = node
    }
  }

  renderCategoryTouts = () => {
    console.log('render category tout')
    categoryTouts.map((tout, index) => {
      return (
        <Tout
          key={tout.title}
          {...tout}
          scrollViewRef={this.state.scrollRef}
          scrollOffset={this.scrollOffsetValue}
        />
      )
    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log('render')
    let categoryTouts = this.scrollRef ? this.renderCategoryTouts() : null
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView
          scrollEventThrottle={1}
          ref={this.setScrollRef}
          onScroll={this.handleScroll}
        >
          <View>
            {categoryTouts}
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 40,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  toutText: {
    color: 'white', backgroundColor: 'transparent', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 24
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('scrollAccordion', () => scrollAccordion);
```

which is not returning any content from the `renderCategoryTouts` function.

I know that initially, `this.scrollRef` is undefined, so the main render function will return `{null}` for the `{categoryTouts}` variable. But after the scrollRef is set, I need it to return the results of `renderCategoryTouts`. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In renderCategoryTouts function of yours you have a variable categoryTouts variabke. You have never declared a variable like that in this function so I assume it is a global variable.

```
 renderCategoryTouts = () => {
    categoryTouts.map((tout, index) => {
      return (
        <Tout
          key={tout.title}
          {...tout}
          scrollViewRef={this.state.scrollRef}
          scrollOffset={this.scrollOffsetValue}
        />
      )
    })
  }
```

And in this function you're using this.state.scrollRef, this.scrollOffsetValue so you need to bind this function.(I suggest you do that in the constructor of class)

this.renderCategoryTouts = this.renderCategoryTouts.bind(this)

also in case this does not work full code would be very helpful

Comment: - I updated this code to include a full example of what I have. If I look at the console logs, 'render' will fire first, then 'setScrollRef' and, therefore, `render category tout` will not fire at all, as the render method is never re-triggered

Comment: it is normal behavior. In setScrollRef function you have not set any state of component. If you use setState in this function it will be rerendered. Aldo in renderCategoryTouts function you have this.state.scrollRef but you've never setState of scrollRef. Instead you can use this.scrollRef or setState of component in setSCrollRef function     (this.setState(scrollRef:node). Don't forget to bind your functions in the constructor in order to call this.setState or reach this. Also I think it is interesting that you are filling content after assigning a ref you should check lifecycle methods.